# .Net MVC UserControl - RenderPartial or EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, renderpartial, editorfor

I have a View that contains a usercontrol. The usercontrol is rendered using:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("GeneralStuff", Model.General, ViewData); %>
```

**My problem is that** the usercontrol renders nicely with values from the model but when I post **values** edited in the usercontrol they **are not mapped back to Model.General**. I know I can find the values in Request.Form but I really thought that MVC would manage to map these values back to the model.

My usercontrol:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<namespace.Models.GeneralViewModel>" %>

<fieldset>        
    <div>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value)%>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Value)%>            
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I'm using .Net MVC 2

Thanks for any help!

Comment: how are you trying to send the value back to the model? through an input?

Comment: Yes, in an input text element. See my code snippet above (<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Value)%>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

My usercontrol is rendered with:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.General); %>
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class TestEditViewModel
{
    [UIHint("GeneralViewModel")]
    public GeneralViewModel General { get; set; }
}
```

And my usercontrol is placed under Views->Shared->EditorTemplates and named "GeneralViewModel.ascx"